# Show authorization popup to editor in sheet Interface instead of running any function manually in google script code editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm working on scripts of google spreadsheet, situation is that a html dialog template would be generated when an edit trigger is triggered.

```
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onEditSimulation')
    .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActive())
    .onEdit()
    .create();
```

And there is a button on the html template, what binding on **onclick** is :

```
onclick = "google.script.run
                   .withSuccessHandler(sended)
                   .withUserObject(this)
                   .resendSpreadSheet(<?=newMail?>)
```

server-side function binding on button would function normally after  runs it at code editor and the process of authorization is completed.
The spreadsheet is going to share with other users, but the manner mentioned above is really not friendly and smoothly to my target user, I strongly wanna avoid that. Is there any solution to make authorization popup just show at the sheet Interface?

Comment: If you call a sheet function `onEdit` and they haven't authenticated, they'll be pushed to the authentication window by default.

Comment: @Brian unfortunately the installabe trigger is required in my situation, there are some API calling like `addEditor` from potection class in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement a small script that asks the "unauthorized user" to manually run a menu option that would trigger the authorization process.

This function would run only once of course.

Code example below :

```
function onOpen() {
  if(! PropertiesService.getUserProperties().getProperty("authorized")){
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Authorize').addItem('Authorize',authorize).addToUi();
    var ui = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setTitle('Authorization request');
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(ui,'Authorization request');
  }
}

function authorize(){
  PropertiesService.getUserProperties().setProperty("authorized", "done");
}
```

index.html :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
Please select the "Authorize " option from the menu<br><br>
<input type="button" value="then close this window"
  onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @insas, thank you for answering, it seems that this is the only good way for what I wanna achieve. Could you explain more about the purpose to `setSandboxMode()`? I have reviewed the [document](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setSandboxMode(SandboxMode)) several times but lack of experience to understand what the real effect would be caused. It would be  appreciated if you could update this part to answer ^^" Thanks again!

Comment: the sandBoxMode is indeed not necessary anymore, forgive me for having used it but it's kind of an old habit ... Some time ago HTML service has 2 other modes : native and emulated that used a kind of "code translator" called CAJA that was intended to prevent malware in google apps script code but now all this is history, you can simply ignore this !  Btw, thanks for accepting.